# getBoundingClientRect coordinates vs SVG

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, svg

I am trying to show relations between items by connecting them via svg lines. When my panel container and the svg element both are at position (0,0) everything works as expected. But if both of them move to another position on the document the coordinate systems seem to get out of sync.

I solved the problem by defining

```
svg{
min-width:100%;
min-height:100%;
z-index: 2;
top:0;
left:0;
position:fixed;
}
```

but that feels super hacky.

How can I get my getBoundingClientRect coordinates (absolute coordinates) in sync with the SVG-coordinates (relative to parent position)?

my JS Code:

```
var panel1 = angular.element(document.querySelector("#panel1"))[0].getBoundingClientRect();
var panel2 = angular.element(document.querySelector("#panel6"))[0].getBoundingClientRect();


element.find("svg").append(SVGTemplatesService.line(
       panel1.right,
       panel1.top + (panel1.height / 2),
       panel2.left,
       panel2.top + (panel2.height / 2)));
```

and the actual drawing happens here:

```
function SVGTemplatesService(){

    var line = function(x1,y1,x2,y2,color){
        color = color || '#333';
        var newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line');
            newLine.setAttribute('x1',x1);
            newLine.setAttribute('y1',y1);
            newLine.setAttribute('x2',x2);
            newLine.setAttribute('y2',y2);
            newLine.setAttribute('style','stroke-width: 5px; stroke: ' + color);
        return newLine;
    };

    return {
        line: line
    }
}
```

[image: connected panels - how it should look like]

Comment: sounds like you should be working in local co-ordinates (via getBBox) rather than global co-ordinates (getBoundingClientRect).

Comment: getBBox ist not a function if I replace getBoundingClientRect with it. How would I use it correctly?

Comment: @ManuKaracho can you clarify what the "panels" are?  Are they SVG elements or something else?

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse they are just plain bootstrap <div class="panel">...</div> elements

Comment: I believe getBBox only applies to SVG elements.  The coordinates to create the line need to be local within the SVG, so presumably just subtracting the left and top bounds of the SVG element itself from each X or Y coordinate is all you need to do

Comment: thanks stuart! sometimes it's so easy... substracting the parent's offset did the trick!

Comment: ....until you reach pan + zoom within SVG, along with ctrl_+ (browser zoom) and mouse scroll down, then you need more offset calculations

Comment: @AlvinK. What kind of calculations would that be?

Comment: Similar offset calculation, map the SVG element in relation to the `<svg..` window (includes scale + transform), then map that in relation to the browser zoom + scroll and finally in relation to the position on monitor screen.