# Bootstrap popover with SVG element from file is wrongly positioned

Tags: svg, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm trying to show bootstrap popover by click on svg circle. SVG content is loaded from file:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" id="svgobj" data="test.svg"></object>
```

Now I have 2 issues:

1) Wrong position of a popover

2) After closing by "x" button a popover shows again only on second button click

```
  var svg = document.getElementById("svgobj");
  var svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;
  var circle = $(svgDoc.getElementById("circle"));
  var opts = {
    title: '<span class="text-info">Title</span><button type="button" id="close" class="close" onclick="$(&quot;.popover&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">&times;</button>',
    html: true,
    content: 'Content',
    trigger: 'click',
    placement: 'auto',
    container: 'body'
  };

  circle.popover(opts);
```

Plunker is here http://plnkr.co/edit/HwQhJEGSZIf8f6JxilEI?p=preview

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515685/getboundingclientrect-coordinates-vs-svg?noredirect=1#comment60684879_36515685 - you need to translate the SVG coordinates (with zoom) to browser window coordinates (with browser zoom and window scroll), which means figuring out the offset of circle in relation to SVG and SVG offset in relation to the browser and monitor screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to proper positioning of a popover I've used d3.js to load SVG from file:

```
svg = d3.select("#svgplace")
.append('svg:svg')
.attr('width', "600px")
.attr('height', "600px")

d3.xml("test.svg", "image/svg+xml", function (error, xml) {
    if (error) throw error;
    var importedNode = document.importNode(xml.documentElement, true);
    var clone = importedNode.cloneNode(true);
    document.querySelector("svg").appendChild(clone);
}
```

2-nd issue caused by the bug in bootstrap since v3.3.5:
[Tooltip/Popover methods show/hide/toggle don't work properly with click triggering](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16732)

Fix:

```
if ($.fn.popover.Constructor.VERSION == "3.3.5" || $.fn.popover.Constructor.VERSION == "3.3.6") {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').on("hidden.bs.popover", function() {
    $(this).data("bs.popover").inState.click = false
  })
}
```